# Generate a JavaDoc comment

Tags: code-golf

I'm too lazy to write a [JavaDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) comment myself, there's a lot of typing and it is mostly boilerplate. Write a program to generate a JavaDoc comment with `$` as a placeholder given a method specification.

Example input:

```
Integer method(int arg1, String arg2) throws InvalidArgumentException, NullPointerException
```

Example output:

```
/**
    $
@param arg1 $
@param arg2 $
@return $
@throws InvalidArgumentException $
@throws NullPointerException $
*/
```

Some notes:

- There won't be any `static`, `private`, or other qualifier on the method, just the return type.
- There should be no `@return` tag if the return type is `void`.
- It is possible that there won't be any `throws` clause.
- You should accept the one-line method spec on stdin and write the result to stdout.

Shortest code wins.

Comment: The javadoc comments on the Wikipedia page show leading ` * ` on the second to [penultimate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/penultimate#Adjective) lines.  Could you either change the example output to match it, or clarify that no leading ` * ` should be printed?

Comment: @Joey - the `*` you mention are optional in Javadoc comments - they are not needed for this question.

Comment: What's about arrays and generic types as param/return type? They introduce new opportunity for blanks. Do we assume all delimiters being blanks, or may they be tabs? After a comma - is there always a blank (or a tab)?

Comment: You may assume that all types will be space-free (but as you point out, they may have `[]<>` characters in them).  You may also assume that all blank spaces are composed of space characters only (i.e., no tabs).  There may or may not be spaces surrounding (both before and after) a comma.

Comment: the @return tag for that input shouldn't be `@return Integer $`?

Comment: Can we assume all input to be valid?

Comment: JBernado: The return *type* is already in the method signature. Why mention it a second time? While Java is happy to duplicate visible information elsewhere this isn't such a case.

Comment: Are all blanks guaranteed to be only one space character or can there be more? I.e. `void     foo()   throws A    ,B`. Will `throws` always be separated by a space from the `)`? Will there never be a space after the method name?

Comment: Can the method be generic? And if so, does the generic type argument be included in the JavaDoc?

Comment: @Joey: there may be any number of spaces, including zero, between any alphanumeric token and any punctuation token.  In other words, anything that would be legal java code (with the exception that I'm restricting all types to be space-free).

Comment: @Joey: no, the method will not be generic.  But the return and argument types might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ruby, <strike>177</strike> <strike>182</strike> 186

```
a,e=gets.split /\bthrows\b/
a=a.split /[\s(),]+/
puts'/**
    $',3.step(a.size,2).map{|i|"@param #{a[i]} $"},a[0]=='void'?[]:'@return $',e ?e.scan(/\w+/).map{|x|"@throws #{x} $"}:[],'*/'
```

Comment: Doesn't handle generic `throws` types correctly, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 2):

#### PowerShell, 209 <s>213</s>

```
'/**
    $'
($i="$input")-replace'.*\( *| *\).*'-split','-ne''|%{"@param $((-split$_)[1]) $"}
,'@return $'*!($i-clike'void *')
if($i-match'\) *t'){$i-replace'.*\) *throws *'-split' *, *'|%{"@throws $_ $"}}'*/'
```

[bash](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/CG3241/Tests/test) and [PowerShell](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/CG3241/Tests/test.ps1) test scripts. but I'm probably missing a few cases still. But 22 tests are better than only one example, I guess :-)

Comment: Wow, for an untrained eye, it looks as unreadable as the Perl script below... :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Perl 5.14 - 192 bytes**

```
#!perl -n
print'/**
    $
';@F=split/\(|\) throws +|\)/;print"\@param $_ \$
"for values{split/[, ]+/,$F[1]};print(($F[0]!~/^void /?'@return $
':''),(map{"\@throws $_ \$
"}$F[2]=~/\w+/g),"*/")
```

Comment: This fails when there is no space between the closing parenthesis and `throws`.

Answer (score 0):

#### scala 579:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
object M extends JavaTokenParsers{def i=ident
type P=Parser[Any]
def r:P=n~"("~rep(p)~")"~opt("throws"~rep(t))^^(s=>"\n/**\n    $"+s._1._1._2.mkString("")+s._1._1._1+"\n2:"+(s._2.getOrElse(""))+"\n*/")
def n:P=i~i^^(s=>if(s._1=="void")""else"\nreturn $")
def p:P=i~i~opt(",")^^(s=>("\n@param "+s._1._2+" $"))
def t:P=i~opt(",")^^(s=>("\n@throws "+s._1+" $"))
def main (args:Array[String])={val i=parseAll(r,readLine())
println(i.toString().replaceAll(".:.*","").replaceAll("[~(),]","").replaceAll("^[\\[].*","").replaceAll ("\n\n","\n"))}}
```

I'm sorry, I'm not experienced with TokenParsers. I guess I'm doing it wrong, and there is much room for improvement.